# Mongoid error only solved adding rspec at the project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid

This error was raised when I tryed, in `rails console`, access a model class:

```
Post.all.first
```

Full error description:

```
Mongoid::Errors::NoClientConfig: 
message:
  No configuration could be found for a client named 'default'.
summary:
  When attempting to create the new client, Mongoid could not find a client configuration for the name: 'default'. This is necessary in order to know the host, port, and options needed to connect.
resolution:
  Double check your mongoid.yml to make sure under the clients key that a configuration exists for 'default'. If you have set the configuration programatically, ensure that 'default' exists in the configuration hash.
    from /home/vagrant/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/mongoid-f539cc6acd28/lib/mongoid/clients/factory.rb:26:in `create'
    from /home/vagrant/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/mongoid-f539cc6acd28/lib/mongoid/clients.rb:64:in `with_name'
    from /home/vagrant/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/mongoid-f539cc6acd28/lib/mongoid/persistence_context.rb:111:in `client'
    from /home/vagrant/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/mongoid-f539cc6acd28/lib/mongoid/persistence_context.rb:71:in `collection'
    from /home/vagrant/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/mongoid-f539cc6acd28/lib/mongoid/clients/options.rb:73:in `collection'
    from /home/vagrant/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/mongoid-f539cc6acd28/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:324:in `initialize'
    from /home/vagrant/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/mongoid-f539cc6acd28/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:53:in `new'
    from /home/vagrant/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/mongoid-f539cc6acd28/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:53:in `create_context'
    from /home/vagrant/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/mongoid-f539cc6acd28/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:35:in `context'
    from /home/vagrant/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/mongoid-f539cc6acd28/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:20:in `first'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /vagrant/sample_mongoid/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I've tryed some suggestions found in other simmilar questions here, but nothing solved.

What solved my problem was add the rspec to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.4'
```

My question is: and if I don't want to use rspec, but Unit Tests instead, how can I do that? Or it's mandatory use rspec with mongoid?

UPDATE1:

My mongoyd.yml:

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: sample_mongoid_development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false

test:
  clients:
    default:
      database: sample_mongoid_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        read:
          mode: :primary
        max_pool_size: 1
```

Comment: getting records from console has nothing to do with rspec. What does `Rails.env` in the console?

Comment: @kasperite, "development".

Comment: can you paste your `mongoid.yml` in the question?

Comment: Updated, @kasperite.

Comment: can't really see any issue here. It's likely the configuration somewhere as it's super weird that adding rspec-rails can fix this

Comment: Well, this project is a sample project where I was testing rails with mongodb. Today I created a new project, following the same steps, and the error didn't happen. The only thing different here is that I'm using other vagrant box. Maybe the problem was related to that.

Comment: Ah right, I did noticed vagrant and different ruby versions in your error log